# Unconditional convergence implies convergence of sum of norm squares in hilbert space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, (.,.))$ be a Hilbertspace and consider the definition of unconditional convergence, i.e. for a set $I \neq \emptyset$ and a family of vectors $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $H$ the series
$$ \sum_{i \in I}x_i$$
is said to be unconditional convergent to a value $x \in H$, if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite $I_0 \subseteq I$ such that
$$ \left\lVert \sum_{i \in \tilde{I}}x_i - x\right\rVert<\epsilon$$
for all finite $\tilde{I} \supseteq I_0$.

Using this definition I wanted to prove that the unconditional convergence of a series $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ in $H$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lVert x_n \rVert^2$.

Using unconditional convergence of $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n =\colon y$ and the fact that the inner product is linear and continuous in each argument we deduce that

$$(y,y) = (\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}x_n, \sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}}x_m) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}}(x_n, x_m)$$

and analogously for the sums interchanged. Here, the sums on the right side converge unconditionally. From there I want to infer, and I don't know how to do that step, that
$$ \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}(x_n,x_m)$$
converges unconditionally, which would then lead me to the unconditional convergence of
$$ \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}\lvert (x_n,x_m) \rvert.$$

Hence we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lVert x_n \rVert^2 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(x_n, x_n) \leq \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}\lvert (x_n,x_m) \rvert.$$
Thus my question is if is this is correct and if so, how can the step which I highlighted with "I don't know how to do" be justified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unconditional convergence of $\sum x_n$ does not imply the convergence of $\sum \|x_n\|^2$ in **all** Banach spaces.

Comment: This reference, [*A Basis Theory Primer* by Cristopher Heil](https://heil.math.gatech.edu/papers/bases.pdf), gives three different proofs of your claim in Hilbert spaces starting at page $32$ (this is the unexpanded version so the numerotation may be different for the more recent version), but states that it's not true in all Banach spaces. It doesn't give a counterexample though.

Comment: @BrunoB A counterexample would be $x_n= (0,0, \ldots, 0,1/n^{1/2},0, \ldots)\in c_0$, where the $1/n^{1/2}$ value occurs in the $n^{th}$ coordinate. Then $\sum x_n = (1/1^{1/2},1/2^{1/2},1/3^{1/2},1/4^{1/2}, \ldots)$, and the convergence is unconditional. But $\sum \|x_n\|^2=\sum 1/n=\infty$.

Comment: @bangs Thank you!

Comment: @BrunoB This was my source too. However the essential part of the first proof  the author proposes is Theorem 2.13, which is proved for general Banach spaces. I was wondering if there is an easier way to prove that part in the context of hilbert spaces.

Comment: @bangs I will correct it, thank you for highlighting that. I got things mixed up.